# If I think an accepted answer is incorrect, how should I respond?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If I think an accepted answer is incorrect, how should I respond?

What I have done
is to submit my own answer
with a comment at the beginning
stating my belief that
the accepted answer was incorrect.

Is there anything else that
I can or should do?

Comment: You can comment on the other answer to see how its author responds. You can also comment on the question to notify the asker of your belief, so (s)he can evaluate the merits of the conflicting claims. (And, shouldn't that be a meta question?)

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10133/should-moderators-intervene-when-the-accepted-answer-is-blatantly-wrong

Comment: NB. The relevant answer has been unaccepted and deleted.

Comment: @Closevoters: This is *not* a duplicate of the [suggested duplicate.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10133/23353).  That question is talking about a moderator's action, this one is talking about a normal user's action.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What I have done is to submit my own answer with a comment at the beginning stating my belief that the accepted answer was incorrect.
>
> Is there anything else that I can or should do?

Both of what you did are entirely within the spirit of how this site operates. The only additional thing that I can think of would be to downvote the incorrect answer.

Comment: And mention it on meta if needed!

Comment: And add a comment on the downvoted answer (as always, except for clearly rubbish answers).